# Por que no funciona mi archivo javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

este es mi código:

```
<script src="resource_path('js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js')"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $('#ModalProducto').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $('.focus').focus();
          })
        });
        @yield('jscript')
    </script>
```

Descargué el js porque necesito que esto funcione offline, si yo lo dejo de la siguiente forma el codigo funciona:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $('#ModalProducto').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $('.focus').focus();
          })
        });
        @yield('jscript')
    </script>
```

Que puedo hacer? trabajo con laravel incluso coloque el js en el webpack pero al parecer algo hago mal porque no me funciona el archivo, podrían ayudarme?

Comment: Estas seguro que el path esta bien?

Comment: En qué carpeta tenés el archivo `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`? Revisá el HTML generado por Laravel y fijate que ruta está generando en el `src`.

Comment: Estas referenciado mal la ruta del archivo

Comment: el archivo js está en resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js

Answer (score 3):

El helper `resource_path()` lleva al directorio de resources, el cual no es un directorio público, o al menos no debería serlo, por lo cual no puedes acceder a dicho archivo.

Deberías almacenarlo en una ruta similar a `public/js/`, y utiliza el helper `asset()` para referenciar el archivo, también debes incluirlo según la sintaxis de blade:

```
{{ asset('/js/jquery.js') }}
```

Comment: te comento que lo incluí en el webpack de esta forma:                             
        'resources/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
 'resources/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js',
 'resources/js/bootstrap.min.js',
 'resources/js/toastr.js',
 'resources/js/vue.js',
 'resources/js/axios.js',
 'resources/js/app.js',
 ], 'public/js/app.js').                                                                                         incluso lo puse antes de la otra librería javascript y no me funciona.

Comment: SI lo pusiste en webpack, al hacer un `npm run production` (o lo que sea), esos archivos se mueven a otra carpeta. Esa otra carpeta no es `resources`, es -o debería ser- una carpeta pública como dice Shaz.

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya lo resolví me ayudo mucho el comentario de Shaz, creo que resource no es una carpeta accesible, entonces aunque enrute allí laravel no puede acceder.

Comment: No es Laravel el que no puede acceder, es el navegador. De hecho Laravel **sí** puede acceder.

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Mau? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde y te dará 2 puntos de reputación). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!